# Read value of an array - JAVA/Android

Tags: java, android

The seems like it would be easy and basic but I just don't know enough about Java/Android and don't know  how to get a specific value from an array. Do you have to iterate though it or can you just call the key/value pair or smth? Any example would be grateful.

thanks
e.g.

```
String[] x = Pattern.compile(";").split(CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(URL));
```

Now if there is a key of ID how do I get that value which should be the 2nd key? X[1]? Just doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean x[1] doesn't work? Is it giving you an error?

Comment: x[1] should indeed get you the 2nd item in the array. Perhaps the array doesn't contain 2 elements, then you'd get an exception. Might want to check how long it is with 'x.length;' prior to fetching an item.

Comment: It did work. I accidentally had quotes around the number but put it correct in my question. doh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String a = x[0];
String b = x[1];
```

or

```
for (String z : x)
{
   String valor = z;
}
```

I wait help you!

Comment: If my answer realy help you, please, mark my answer with solution of your problem.